# Wordpress permalink not work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, vps, cloudflare

Hy It's me again :) 
I've some problem with my new website, in my website use cloudflare for DNS. If permalink in default mode, It's all right nothing found problem but when permalink change to any and open that post website unavailable or not found in cloudflare. 
I've try replacing permalink with custom permalink example :

```
/%category%/%postname%.html
```

but still doesn't work, same as when I try replacing .htaccess with this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ginc0der.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ htt p://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

or this one

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but still show not available you can view here

> http://ginc0der.com/index.php/archives/category/programming

what exactly is the problem? whether in VPS, htaccess or maybe in cloudflare?
thanks before, I hope you can help me in this problem

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something on your server directly. We wouldn't alter permalinks.